# Why QTableWidgetItem doesn't keep updating it's color?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem

I have a QTableWidget in my program. I want it's rows and columns to change color according to the time entry in the table widget. When I first add the time, it's compared to current system time and the color changing does take effect but as time goes by it doesn't keep up and the colors remain the same. I want it to keep updating table item's color. I cant include all the code as it is too long but I have included the relevant part.

```
#Operations_Tree is the QTABLEWIDGET
def Scheduler_Loop(self):
    Timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
    Timer.start(1000)
    Timer.timeout.connect(self.test)

def test(self):

    time = QtCore.QTime.currentTime()
    current_time_text = time.toString('hh:mm:ss')
    for row in range(0,self.Operations_Tree.rowCount()):
        time = self.Operations_Tree.item(row,1)
        time_text = time.text()
        #print(time_text)
        if time_text >= current_time_text :
            for column in range(0,6):
                #print("TEST")
                try:
                    table_widget_item = self.Operations_Tree.item(row, column)
                    table_widget_item.setForeground(QtGui.QColor(0,0,255)) #BLue
                    table_widget_item.setBackground(QtGui.QColor(238,233,233)) #
                    table_widget_item.viewport.update()
                except AttributeError:
                    pass
        else:
            for column in range(0,6):
                #print("TEST")
                try:
                    table_widget_item = self.Operations_Tree.item(row, column)
                    #table_widget_item.setForeground(QtGui.QColor(0,255,0)) #
                    table_widget_item.setBackground(QtGui.QColor(238,233,233)) #
                    table_widget_item.viewport.update()
                except AttributeError:
                    pass
    self.Operations_Tree.update()
```

here is a snap of my program:

[image]

Comment: The color of 12:12:12 has changed to blue because it is greater than system time.But when system time passed 12:12:12, the color doesn't change to black.

Comment: @eyllanesc the system time format and my whole programs time formats are all in 24 hours.

Comment: @eyllanesc to put it this way for you: if I have set my WidgetItems colors to certain color and then I change it to something new, how can i get the PyQt to repaint it again using the new colors?

Comment: @eyllanesc not very sure what you exactly mean but yes!, it also repaints a QLCDNumber widget that represents current system time using another timer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me the main problem is that you are comparing strings instead of time, also in Qt it is not necessary to use try-except since many times they hide errors and waste unnecessary resources, it is better to verify.

**PyQt5:**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.lcd_number = QtWidgets.QLCDNumber()
        self.lcd_number.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.lcd_number.setFixedHeight(100)
        self.lcd_number.setDigitCount(8)
        self.Operations_Tree = QtWidgets.QTableWidget()
        self.Operations_Tree.setColumnCount(6)
        labels = ["On AIR", "TIME", "ITEM", "DURATION", "B.ITEM", "B.I.DURATION"]
        self.Operations_Tree.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(labels)

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.lcd_number)
        lay.addWidget(self.Operations_Tree)

        for i, t in enumerate(("10:10:10", "12:12:12")):
            self.Operations_Tree.insertRow(self.Operations_Tree.rowCount())
            it = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(t)
            self.Operations_Tree.setItem(i, 1, it)

        self.resize(640, 480)
        self.Scheduler_Loop()

    def Scheduler_Loop(self):
        Timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        Timer.timeout.connect(self.test)
        Timer.start(1000)
        self.test()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def test(self):
        time = QtCore.QTime.currentTime()
        self.lcd_number.display(time.toString())
        for row in range(self.Operations_Tree.rowCount()):
            it = self.Operations_Tree.item(row, 1)
            r_time = QtCore.QTime.fromString(it.text(), "h:mm:ss")
            flag = r_time >= time
            f_color = QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 255) if flag else QtGui.QColor(0, 255, 0)
            b_color = QtGui.QColor(238, 233, 233) if flag else QtGui.QColor(238,233,233)
            for column in range(0, 6):
                it = self.Operations_Tree.item(row, column)
                if it is None:
                    it = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
                    self.Operations_Tree.setItem(row, column, it)
                it.setForeground(f_color)
                it.setBackground(b_color)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**PyQt4:**

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui


class Widget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.lcd_number = QtGui.QLCDNumber()
        self.lcd_number.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.lcd_number.setFixedHeight(100)
        self.lcd_number.setDigitCount(8)
        self.Operations_Tree = QtGui.QTableWidget()
        self.Operations_Tree.setColumnCount(6)
        labels = ["On AIR", "TIME", "ITEM", "DURATION", "B.ITEM", "B.I.DURATION"]
        self.Operations_Tree.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(labels)

        lay = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.lcd_number)
        lay.addWidget(self.Operations_Tree)

        for i, t in enumerate(("10:10:10", "12:12:12")):
            self.Operations_Tree.insertRow(self.Operations_Tree.rowCount())
            it = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(t)
            self.Operations_Tree.setItem(i, 1, it)

        self.resize(640, 480)
        self.Scheduler_Loop()

    def Scheduler_Loop(self):
        Timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        Timer.timeout.connect(self.test)
        Timer.start(1000)
        self.test()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def test(self):
        time = QtCore.QTime.currentTime()
        self.lcd_number.display(time.toString())
        for row in range(self.Operations_Tree.rowCount()):
            it = self.Operations_Tree.item(row, 1)
            r_time = QtCore.QTime.fromString(it.text(), "h:mm:ss")
            flag = r_time >= time
            f_color = QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 255) if flag else QtGui.QColor(0, 255, 0)
            b_color = QtGui.QColor(238, 233, 233) if flag else QtGui.QColor(238,233,233)
            for column in range(0, 6):
                it = self.Operations_Tree.item(row, column)
                if it is None:
                    it = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
                    self.Operations_Tree.setItem(row, column, it)
                it.setForeground(f_color)
                it.setBackground(b_color)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Many thanks for your effort but the problem is not with comparison because when I test it with a print statement, it does behave the way I expect.

Comment: Yes I did convert my tableItem's text to QTime the way you have done it and compared it to system time, it still behave's the way I was comparing strings and didnt solve the problem.

Comment: I am using PyQt4, I dont have PyQt5 installed, will do that tomorrow and let you know, thanks!

Comment: Yes, your code works correctly. Any idea what could be wrong with my code?